# Makefile error "make: *** No rule to make target 'CC', needed by 'cub3d'. Stop." how to solve it?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

What's wrong with my makefile?

This is exactly the error I get
`make: *** No rule to make target 'CC', needed by 'cub3d'.  Stop.`

Makefile

```
SRC = gnl/gnl.c \
    gnl/gnl_utils.c \
    main.c \
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
LIB = libft/libft.a
NAME = cub3d
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(LIB) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)

$(LIB):
    @make all -C libft/

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    @make clean -C libft/

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)
    @make fclean -C libft/

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

I was expecting it to create the cub3d executable.

Comment: Typo: the trailing backslash in `main.c \ ` causes `CC = gcc` to be included in `SRC`

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
SRC = gnl/gnl.c \
    gnl/gnl_utils.c \
    main.c \
    CC = gcc
```

The backslashes on these lines combine them (effectively) into one line, so you have:

```
SRC = gnl/gnl.c gnl/gnl_utils.c main.c CC = gcc
```

thus you have "sources" called `CC` `=` and `gcc`.  `CC` is just the first of these to be looked for, so that is the error you get.

Remove the `\` from the `main.c` line to avoid pulling the `CC` line into your sources

Comment: Chris, clarified *which* line should be changed since that was unclear, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

The last stray backslash in your `SRC` definition:

```
SRC = gnl/gnl.c \
    gnl/gnl_utils.c \
    main.c \
CC = gcc
```

... makes `CC = gcc` a part of `SRC`.
The backslashes "glues" lines together and you don't want `CC = gcc` to become a part of the `SRC` so:

```
SRC = gnl/gnl.c \
    gnl/gnl_utils.c \
    main.c
CC = gcc
```